# How to include a link to live code example in SO question?

Tags: support

I tried to include a link to the place<sup>1</sup> where I build my Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of the code [I included in a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34969640/missing-nodes-in-creation-of-ordered-linked-list), to make it easier for the reader, however the site couldn't load.

Is there a place that could be used to build Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examples, to which later a link could be included in the question?

---

<sup>1. cpp.sh</sup>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All necessary code to understand the question should be in the question itself and not dependent on availability of a third party resource.

As an additional bonus you could copy it to http://ideone.com for a runnable sample.