# How do I include a full working repro for a Windows app?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I ran into an issue while developing a Windows (UWP) application and spent a lengthy amount of time searching for a solution. Finding none, I spent an hour or so recreating the problem in a minimal sample application with as little code as possible before posting a question. Once I had a working example, I posted a [very clear question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60763539/how-do-i-define-a-constant-in-c-sharp-and-use-it-in-xaml) and at the bottom of the question included my working sample in code blocks.

The question was incorrectly closed as a duplicate (separate issue) but the moderator also stated that it should include "a good [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), instead of the above." I took objection to this, having spent an hour of my time expressly to create the minimal reproducible example.

The linked "How to" discusses keeping the example minimal, but it also emphasizes that the example should be *complete*. "Make sure **all** information necessary to reproduce the problem is included in the question itself: If the problem requires some server-side code as well as some XML-based configuration, include code for both. If a web page problem requires HTML, some JavaScript, and a stylesheet, include code for all three. **The problem might not be in the code that you think it is in.**" Another [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315332/how-to-include-a-link-to-live-code-example-in-so-question#315333) specifically states, "All necessary code to understand the question should be in the question itself and not dependent on availability of a third party resource."

The moderator's comments indicate that he only wants to see the lines of code that are expressly related to the problem, not the remaining code that is necessary to actual build a working example: "I'm not going to waste time going through your post line by line, but for example, there's no need for error-handling code for this example, nor all of the XAML markup you've got (one single property binding is sufficient for the task at hand). There is a lot of code in your post that simply does not matter here."

How do I include a minimal reproducible example that will actually run as a Windows app without my question being flagged by moderators for including too much code?

Comment: Note that "moderator" has a specific meaning on Stack Overflow, especially Meta Stack Overflow. Moderators here have diamonds next to their user names and are elected. In this case, it was simply another user (albeit with more reputation and a gold badge in a tag on the question).

Comment: The way you asked the question is just fine, you were unlucky with the users that follow the tags you used.  [c#] attracks in a lot of users that don't know anything about UWP, [uwp-xaml] brings in nobody.  Ideally they'll leave the question for somebody that is willing to dig in, that's a hard ideal to reach.  Hammered back open, good luck.